# Exponential Distributions -- probability at least one customer will arrive in the next half minute?

Tags: probability

Assume the time between arriving customers is exponential distributed with a mean of half a minute.  Assume one minute has gone by since the last customer arrived. What then, is the probability that at least one customer will arrive in the next half minute?

I've determined that λ = 2 since the mean is 1/2.
\begin{align}
P(X \le x) &= 1 - e^{-2x}\\
P(X \le 1) &= 1 - e^{-2}\end{align}

Comment: The exponential distribution is memoryless. Does that help?

Comment: @Paul What does memoryless mean?

Comment: It means that the probability of the next arrival after time t is independent of anything that happened up to time t.

Comment: @Paul Are my edits correct?

Comment: If X is the number of customers that arrive in the next half minute then question wants $P(X>0$ given there has been no customer in the last minute) = $P(X>0)$ since the process is memoryless. This is then $1-P(X = 0)$. What do you know about X given that the inter-arrival time is exponentially distributed?

Comment: X is a Poisson process with rate 1 (per half minute) so that $P(X = 0)=e^{-1}$. In the answer given below it is not clear what X is - is it a number of people or a time? The solution is confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 
The probability you  look for is
$$
P(1<x<1.5 | x>1) = \frac{P(1<x<1.5 \text{ and }P( x>1)}{x>1)}= \frac{P(1<x<1.5)}{P(x>1)}
$$

---

solution:

Using the last expression:
$$
= \frac{P(x>1) - P(x> 1.5)}{P(x>1)} = \frac{e^{-2} - e^{-3}}{e^{-2}} = 1-e^{-1}
$$

Note that this is also $1-P(X>1.5 - 1)$. The same way you can prove that
$$
P(X>t+h | X>t) = P(X>h)
$$
This is why the exponential variable is said to be memoryless.